# My yamaha delight 2014 moped died total electric fail

Tags: ignition

My moped died the other day after running well
Totally no power to ignition lights or any starter noise flat dead I changed fuse  checked battery with meter even put booster on it nothing done lot of research and quite knowledgeable hoping it's the starter relay  and not the cdi il continue to follow faults down the loom n check ever wire n connection any advice apreciated as just got it all road legal and got back on road after many years

Answer (score 1):

If this moped uses a magneto to operate ignition for spark and headlight/tail lights, this may a wiring issue. If electric start, the ignition switch and starter wiring may be the problem. Both problems may be related to the ignition switch. A wiring diagram is needed or knowledge of relatively simple wiring systems related to mopeds.